# Put <div> over another <div> CSS

Tags: html, css

What iam trying to do is to put a  with two imagebuttons over another  which is used only for the backround-color.

For example: [image]

How can i put the div with the two buttons over the backround exact like in the attached image.

My Code so far:

CSS:

```
.behind
    {
        background-color: #e2e0de;
        width: 100%;
        height: 130px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <div>
            <div class="behind">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCheckin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/button1.png"
                CssClass="checkinButton" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCheckout" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/button2.png"
                CssClass="checkoutButton divider" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

With my Code is looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images are wrapped in the `behind` div, so they start at the same point your background does. First, move them out:

```
<div>
        <div class="behind"></div>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCheckin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/button1.png"
            CssClass="checkinButton" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCheckout" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/button2.png"
            CssClass="checkoutButton divider" />
</div>
```

Secondly, update the `.behind` css to start at an absolute position (i.e. not from the top). Notice the `position: absolute` and the `top: 20px` elements. **Just replace 20px with a value suitable for you, depending on the size of the images**.

```
.behind {
    background-color: #e2e0de;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

**[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16mqLy65/)**, but I've used other images so the value for the `top:` offset is different.

Answer (score 0):

try this it might help **(UNTESTED)** :

```
.checkoutButton
    {
        position:relative;
        top:-value;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

**PS :** change the `value` to a a real value for exemple if your buttons height was `136px` then give it `-3px` -> ((buttons height-divs height)/2).

i hope it helps and sorry for not testing it i can't at the moment